# Pod level route restriction

Tags: openshift

EDITED:

I have a service running in OpenShift on 2 pods, let's call them *P1* and *P2*.

The service does two things:

1. An API
2. We listen to Kafka messages from a topic and then process them.

Is there a way I can restrict all calls made to API only to *P1* and all calls for Kafka only to *P2* ?

Comment: Well, routes point to a Service, and services match their pods based on labels. If your pods have 2 different services with 2 different label matching, then the routes would stay separated.

Comment: Alternatively, there are cookies that get set by default when going through a route to ensure that once a connection is established, that connections stays with the same pod....this is used for sessions, etc. But that happens when using the same route. From your question it doesn't seem clear _what_ you're trying to do, or _why_ you're trying to do it

Comment: I'll clarify things a little:
I have a service running. That service does two things:

1. There is an endpoint to which it listens to (API).

2. We listen for Kafka messages on a topic and then process those messages.


Is there a way I can make one pod only work on Kafka while the other pod only handles the API part.

Comment: Maybe Path-Based Routes are what you are looking for: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#path-based-routes Otherwise I would suggest you look into what Will suggested above and create 2 different services with 2 different routes, as this seems to be what you want.

Comment: I'll look into the link attached.
Otherwise, I think splitting it into two services is the more viable solution. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked what NetworPolicies can do?

Comment: @titou10 I did go through them, but they don't seem to allow pod level restrictions according to the case I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion may not fit with your requests, but if each one pod is running in a specific project, then it would be available as follows.

First, you should configure pod's source IP statically using Egress IP based on project level, refer [Enabling Static IPs for External Project Traffic](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_networking.html#enabling-static-ips-for-external-project-traffic) for more details.

```
$ oc patch netnamespace p1_project -p '{"egressIPs": ["1.1.1.1"]}'

$ oc patch netnamespace p2_project -p '{"egressIPs": ["2.2.2.2"]}'
```

After that, you can allow each pod IP based on whitelist, refer [Route-specific IP Whitelists](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#whitelist) for more details.

```
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: R1
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: 1.1.1.1
```

```
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: R2
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: 2.2.2.2
```

I hope it help you.

Comment: Interesting. But that's not the case. I only have 1 project that I'm running on 2 pods and I want to restrict my routes only to a particular pod.
Thanks, though!